# How to build libfetch in linux?

Tags: linux, build, fetch

As is known for us all, source code for libfetch.so is not originally designed for redhat linux,and I have searched and tried many times, failed ,but I know someone has successfully made it previously.
Of course, commonly used ./confgure --parameter && make && make install will fail immediately, for the simple reason that it has no configure file(or something like that) at all!
source code download: http://www.filewatcher.com/m/libfetch-2.33.tar.gz.46611-0.html
so, can someone of you help me ?

Comment: Edit its `Makefile` till `make` works ok. But you should rather use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build `libfetch` on Linux Mint using the Makefile which is available from the Alpine Linux `aports` repo. (It is very different from the BSD Makefile which comes with the `libfetch` source.) All the other source code was unchanged.